# How to format unordered list in collapsible content

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little bit of an issue with an unordered list inside a collapsible content `div`.  While the `div` is collapsing, The list appears without any styling; But, after the `div` finishes collapsing all the way, my css takes over and it displays with styling.

I will add my entire code here.  If you click on "My Routes" you'll understand what I'm talking about.  It's kinda tricky to explain.

Thanks,
Richard.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* Every CSS rule for the Sidebar and it's contents */

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.collapse {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.collapse ul li {
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E6EA;
}

.collapse ul li:hover {
  background-color: #e2e6ea;
}

.collapse i {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-KA6wR/X5RY4zFAHpv/CnoG2UW1uogYfdnP67Uv7eULvTveboZJg0qUpmJZb5VqzN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myroutes">My Routes</button>
      <div id="myroutes" class="collapse">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              10/29/19 - Montgomery & Butler County
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>

            </li>
            <li>
              10/12/19 - Clinton & Highland County
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
              10/05/19 - Indiana
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are applying your styles to the list based on the parent having the class `collapse` which it won't have during the collapsing event but only when completed. A better way would be to add a class to your list `<ul class="my-styled-list">` and then target that in your css with `.my-styled-list { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% it will work..!

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your style for your unorder list, `ul`, is dependent on `.collapse` class being defined on the parent element.

The reason it isn't applying while the `div` is collapsing is because `collapse` is replaced with `collapsing` on the `div` during that scenario.

See Components **[Collapse - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/)** documentation.

---

There are several implementations you could do here, but the one that makes the most sense to me is to define and apply your styles that account for `collapsing` - accounting of that state change.

That is, everywhere you are declaring a style selector for `collapse`, you should also declare for `collapsing` (where it makes sense to do so).

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* Every CSS rule for the Sidebar and it's contents */

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.collapse, 
.collapsing {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.collapse ul,
.collapsing ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.collapse ul li,
.collapsing ul li {
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E6EA;
}

.collapse ul li:hover,
.collapsing ul li:hover {
  background-color: #e2e6ea;
}

.collapse i,
.collapsing i {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-KA6wR/X5RY4zFAHpv/CnoG2UW1uogYfdnP67Uv7eULvTveboZJg0qUpmJZb5VqzN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myroutes">My Routes</button>
      <div id="myroutes" class="collapse">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              10/29/19 - Montgomery & Butler County
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>

            </li>
            <li>
              10/12/19 - Clinton & Highland County
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
              10/05/19 - Indiana
              <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Note:

some styles (like `font-size`) that are declared on `div.collapse` (and `div.collapsing`) are inherited by their child elements so that is also a consideration here as well.